# Is there limit to number of elements in layout of ArcGIS Pro project manipulated by ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, limitations

Has anyone encountered, or aware of, a limit to the number of elements in an ArcGIS Pro layout that is manipulated by ArcPy?

The reason I ask is that I have created an ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1 project that has one layout and six map frames that I have been happily running a large ArcPy script against that finishes by exporting to PDF and then saving a copy of the project.

As part of the code I incorporate writing a table that incorporates cloning hundreds of text and graphics elements, and this is based on [TextElement example 2](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/textelement-class.htm#C_GUID-8E97A6FA-75D3-41D8-A627-969AA0949976) from the ArcGIS Pro documentation which:

> constructs a graphic table based on data values from a table in a map.
>   The layout was authored with a vertical line named vertLine, a
>   horizontal line named horzLine, and a text element named cellText.
>   Each of the elements were authored with the appropriate symbology and
>   text properties. The element's anchors were also set to the upper left
>   position, and the text element's vertical and horizontal justification
>   were set to upper left.

That works fine but when I add more code to implement a workaround that I am developing for measured grids (because they are not supported until ArcGIS Pro 2.x) that also creates about a hundred text elements, this new set of text elements do not appear in the exported PDF or the project saved as a copy, but using `print` statements in the code I can see that they are present in the original manipulated project.

As soon as I comment out the [TextElement example 2](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/textelement-class.htm#C_GUID-8E97A6FA-75D3-41D8-A627-969AA0949976) code, the measured grid text elements start to appear in both the exported PDF and the project saved as a copy.  This leads me to theorize that I have encountered a limit to how many layout elements ArcGIS Pro can support when one of its projects is manipulated by ArcGIS Pro.

I have not yet included a code snippet here, in case someone already has one that they can offer, but I believe I will be able to run up a code snippet that illustrates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is/was an undocumented limit to the number of graphic/text/layout elements at ArcGIS Pro 1.4 (and later, tested to 2.0.1).

To workaround it I dramatically reduced the number of layout elements needed in my project by creating a polygon feature class, representing the table's cells, so that I could outline and label it within a single map frame, that was a window onto a map with a layer that had that feature class as its source.

The technique for doing this, with all code, is available as a Udemy eLearning course titled [Challenging Times with Python and ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro](https://www.udemy.com/challenging-times-with-python-and-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro).

Disclosure: I am the author and presenter of that course which is not free.